# Submit a form in a popup, and then close the popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup

This seemed so trivial when I started off with it! My objective is this:

- When user clicks on a button, open up a form in a new window.
- Once the form is submitted, close the popup and return to the original page. The reverse order is fine too - i.e., I am okay if the popup is closed and then the form submits.

Here's how I'm doing this:

```
<form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return closeSelf()" name="certform">
                <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
                <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>
                <div>Certificate 3: <input type="file" name="cert3"/></div>

                <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></div>
            </form>
```

and the Javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeSelf(){
    self.close();
    return true;
}
</script>
```

This seems to work fine on IE8 and Chrome; but Firefox refuses to submit the form; it just closes the popup. What might I be doing wrong?

### EDIT:

Had forgotten to post the code the opens the popup. Here it is:

```
<div><input type="submit" value="Upload Certificates" onclick="popupUploadForm()"/>
```

And the corresponding javascript:

```
function popupUploadForm(){
        var newWindow = window.open('/cert.html', 'name', 'height=500,width=600');
    }
```

Comment: I saw the same issue on Safari on WinXP as well. So this confuses me further - One Webkit based browser (Chrome) behaves well; another (Safari) does not!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have executed the code in my machine its working for IE and FF also.

```
function closeSelf(){
    // do something

    if(condition satisfied){
       alert("conditions satisfied, submiting the form.");
       document.forms['certform'].submit();
       window.close();
    }else{
       alert("conditions not satisfied, returning to form");    
    }
}


<form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="certform">
       <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
       <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>
       <div>Certificate 3: <input type="file" name="cert3"/></div>

       // change the submit button to normal button
       <div><input type="button" value="Upload"  onclick="closeSelf();"/></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It still doesn't help. I even tried `onsubmit="closeSelf()"` and `onsubmit="closeSelf();"` - all the same: Works fine on IE but not on Firefox. I assume the standards stipulate that you need that semi-colon at the end of onXXX attributes?

Comment: updated the code... check it out... i have tested in my machine.. Its working fine.

Comment: Really appreciate your help dku.rajkumar. This solution works like a charm on IE and FF; but doesn't on Chrome and Safari. I'm beginning to think it may not be possible to achieve what I'm looking for across all browsers!

Comment: I accept your answer since it helped me on my way. I am posting another answer illustrating how I ended up doing this.

Comment: @curioustechizen: Please, don't accept people's answers just because they pushed you towards the right direction. You can upvote the answers, sure, but accepting a wrong/incomplete solution is confusing to people who stumble upon the question. If your answer is "more correct", accept yours.

Comment: @baash05 I'm years late....but I just posted an answer here that solves the problem with it closing before it fully submits the data. If you pass the information to a function and have the function itself do the submission, you can have it submit fully prior to it closing the window. I've tested it on all of the major browsers and it works fine across them as of Apr '15.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across it when I was having a similar issue, and just wanted to share how I ended achieving the results you requested so future people can pick what works best for their situation.

First, I utilize the `onsubmit` event in the form, and pass `this` to the function to make it easier to deal with this particular form.

```
<form action="/system/wpacert" onsubmit="return closeSelf(this);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="certform">
    <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
    <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>
    <div>Certificate 3: <input type="file" name="cert3"/></div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></div>
</form>
```

In our function, we'll submit the form data, and then we'll close the window. This will allow it to submit the data, and once it's done, then it'll close the window and return you to your original window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function closeSelf (f) {
     f.submit();
     window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone out. Enjoy!

---

Option 2: This option will let you submit via AJAX, and if it's successful, it'll close the window. This prevents windows from closing prior to the data being submitted. Credits to http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ for their work on the jQuery Form Plugin

First, remove your onsubmit/onclick events from the form/submit button. Place an ID on the form so AJAX can find it.

```
<form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="certform">
    <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
    <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>
    <div>Certificate 3: <input type="file" name="cert3"/></div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></div>
</form>
```

Second, you'll want to throw this script at the bottom, don't forget to reference the plugin. If the form submission is successful, it'll close the window.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#certform').ajaxForm(function () {
          window.close();
          });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do a similar thing but I am unable to achieve it. Could you please have a look at this and let me know how I can get it to work? My form submits but the window doesn't close. Any suggestions why?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369009/close-opened-pop-up-window-on-form-submission-and-trigger-click-on-the-parent-wi

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I ended up doing this:

```
        <div id="divform">
            <form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="certform">
                <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
                <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>

                <div><input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="closeSelf();"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div  id="closelink" style="display:none">
            <a href="javascript:window.close()">Click Here to Close this Page</a>
        </div>

function closeSelf(){
    document.forms['certform'].submit();
    hide(document.getElementById('divform'));
    unHide(document.getElementById('closelink'));

}
```

Where `hide()` and `unhide()` set the `style.display` to `'none'` and `'block'` respectively.

Not exactly what I had in mind, but this will have to do for the time being. Works on IE, Safari, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution on top won't work because a submit redirects the page to the endpoint of form and wait for response to redirect.
I see that this is an old Question but Most Asked and even i came to know the answer.Still here is my solution what i am implementing.
I tried to keep it secure with Nonce but if you don't care then not required.

**Method 1:**
You need to Pop up the form.

```
document.getElementById('edit_info_button').addEventListener('click',function(){
        window.open('URLHERE','newwindow', 'width=400,height=600,scrollbars=no');
    });
```

Then you have the form open.

> Submit the form normally.

Then return an HTTPResponse containing a htmlfile With a STRICT Content Security Policy.
A Variable that contains the following script. Nonce contains a Base64 128bits or larger randomly generated string for every request made to server.

> `<script nonce="NONCE_VALUE_HERE">window.close()</script>`

**Method 2:**

Or you can redirect to another Page which is suppose to close ...
Which already Contains the `window.close()` script.
This will close the pop up window.

**Method 3:**

Otherwise the simplest will be Use a Ajax call if you are comfortable with one.Use [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and check your condition to the *httpresponse* from the server.Close the window when success.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as well

```
covertPostSub("/xyz/test.jsp","?param1=param1&param2=param2","_self","true");
covertPostSub("/xyz/test.jsp","?param1=param1&param2=param2","_blank","true");

var convPop = null;
function covertPostSub(action,paramsTosend,targetIframe,isWindow){
    var Popup = null;
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("id","TheForm");
    form.setAttribute("action", action);
    form.setAttribute("target", targetIframe);
    var params = paramsTosend;
    params = params.substring(1, params.length);
    params = params.split("&");
    for(var key=0; key<params.length; key++) {
        var sa = params[key];
        sa = sa.split("=");
        var xs = (sa[1]);

        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", sa[0]);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value",xs);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.style.display = "none";
    if(isWindow){
        window.open('', "formpopup","width=900,height=590,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,left=60,top=60");
        form.target = 'formpopup';
        form.submit();
    }else{
        form.submit();
    }

}
```